# Не открываются изображения в OpenCart после перехода на SSL

Tags: opencart, opencart2.0

Подскажите в каких файлах в OpenCart 2.3 нужно поменять данные на SSL.

Без ssl он ставит ссылку такого типа
 `http://dvakotla.com.ua/image/cache/catalog/image.jpg`

А с ssl он ставит почему то вот так `image/cache/catalog/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

В **`root/config.php`**, замените в константе **`HTTP_SERVER`** значение **`http`** на **`https`**

**`Сертификат`** должен быть подписан и в настройках магазина должно быть активировано **`Использовать SSL`**

В .htaccess должны быть настроены зеркала на **`https`**

Это минимальный пул мероприятий, после внедрения которого, в  случае 0-го эффекта, можно будет говорить о некачественном шаблоне.

Comment: сертификат от ClouFlire, все настройки о  которых вы говорите, сделаны.

Comment: @rodgers лого сайта проверьте. оно http  и провоцирует mixedContent

Comment: и изображения отдают 404, они есть по своим путям?

Comment: The requested URL /kotly/elektricheskie-kotly/image/cache/catalog/Protherm Skat 24-500x445.jpg was not found on this server.

Comment: @rodgers Uncaught TypeError: $(...).elevateZoom is not a function

Comment: ну так в этом и проблема, что опенкарт почему то ставит относительные пути когда ставишь SSL.Если SSL убрать то все отлично работает

Comment: наведите в на любую ссылку в devtools'е. Они отображены относительными, но по факту они передают полный путь. Там проблема в другом, хз.

Comment: dvakotla.com.ua/image/cache/catalog/… - такая ссылка должна быть; dvakotla.com.ua/kotly/elektricheskie-kotly/image/cache/catal‌​og/… - такая она сейчас. Т.е. к роуту на изображение и другие подключаемые файлы дописывается категория и подкат. Проверяйте в константы в конфинах.

Comment: Причем тут константы в конфигах? Я же написал все отлично работает когда нет ssl

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена, файлы темы были биты.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.